# setting the view dynamically from the java file

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to make the java file set the view for the activity dinamically by using a specific number of linearlayouts and setting the source images
so how can I use java code to create a specific number of Image Views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menuline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp" >

</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>    



</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question more?

Comment: so i have this xml file ,and without having ro write the same code so many times i want just to duplicate this linearlayout and set the source image for it By using the java code . not the XML .

Comment: Create your imageView in for statement with any number that you want, put all image resurce id in one array and set to your imageView

Comment: I still don't understand what are you trying to get... a ListView with some images inside? It would be as scrollable as a ScrollView, and it would be easily filled by code using a custom row item.

Comment: @Vyger i wann put alll my images in an array  with a variable size for this array  , so how can i call the java code to display the images ?

Comment: It's a perfect case for a ListView, then! Nice [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an ImageView (assuming `this` in an `Activity`):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.set(...) //configure your imageView according your needs
...
imageView.setLayoutParam(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,85); //set width and height
```

To add your imageView to the linearLayout :

```
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```